# Difference between style.width and offsetwidth in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I notice that `offsetwidth` is a slightly bigger number. Similarly for `style.height` and `offsetheight`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Typically, an element's offsetWidth is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element horizontal padding, the element vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered) and the element CSS width.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.offsetWidth

---

So, it's the width of your element with border and padding included. Same thing for height.

Comment: It does not include the margin so this answer is incorrect/

Answer (score 43):

[`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth) returns computed element's width, while [`el.style.width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) just returns width property defined in *element.style* by `javascript` and does not reflect real element's dimensions.

This means that if you will try to get a width of the element by accessing `el.style`, you will probably get nothing ([`sample`](http://codepen.io/sol0mka/pen/arElv)), even if the width was defined in your CSS. You will get the number only if it was defined in `el.style` by `javascript`.

Furthermore, `offsetWidth` gives you real width of your element, including `padding` and `border` if you use `content-box` [`css box model`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) which is default value for `box-sizing`. So you can think about that like you set `width` of the contents of the element and `padding/border` go on top of that ([`sample`](http://codepen.io/sol0mka/pen/LtdBF)).

If you are using *border-box* [`css box model`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing), you set the total width of the element, including `padding` and `border` make the content area smaller ([`sample`](http://codepen.io/sol0mka/pen/IfyHF)). So, in this case, [`offsetWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.offsetWidth) and [`el.style.width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement.style) would return exactly the same numbers (if `el.style.width` was previously set by `javascript`).

Comment: There's some jewels in this answer! Read it carefully!

Answer (score 1):

offsetWidth is a measurement in pixels of the element's CSS width, including any borders, padding, and vertical scrollbars.

clientWidth is the inner width (ie. the space inside an element including padding but excluding borders and scrollbars)

with only return the css with defined