# Why div DOM object does not have height and width properties

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner coder. It is probably very simple, but I tried to find the answer and have not succeeded. My question is why do `width` and `height` properties of `div` object return `undefined` while they are apparently 100px both?

[In this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294250/how-do-i-retrieve-an-html-elements-actual-width-and-height)  is explained how to get `.offsetWidth` property. But as I understand it is not 100% the same as `.width`.

```js
window.onload = function() {

  var test = document.getElementById("test");
  test.addEventListener("click", select);


  function select(e) {
    var elementID = e.target.id;
    var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
    var width = element.width;
    console.log(element);
    console.log(width);
  }

}
```

```css
div#test {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

**My answer**

Thank you all guys for your answers. They pushed me to find my own simple solution which I hope will be helpful for such beginners as me. The answer is: `div` DOM object does not have `.width` and `.height` property even if you assign them in CSS and they work well. For this purpose it has `.style.width` and `.style.height` respectively. But even if you assign them through CSS they will not appear in  `element.style` until you do it purposefully using Java Script. So to get `width` or `height` of the `div` element through JS first of all remove these properties from CSS. You will not need them anymore. Then assign `width` through `element.style.width` command and then you can easily get it whenever you want using `element.style.width`.

**CSS**

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function() {

    var test = document.getElementById("test");
    test.addEventListener("click", select);
    test.style.width = "100px";
    test.style.height = "100px";


    function select(e) {                                  
        var elementID = e.target.id;
        var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
        var width = element.style.width;
        console.log(element);
        console.log(width);
    }

}
```

Comment: `element.style.width`

Comment: you need to use computed style to get width defined by style

Comment: Black Beard, I added a 2nd dupe link, which likely show what you are looking for

Comment: @TemaniAfif If you close it, make sure you reference a proper answer. In this case, and as I guess you meant in a comment, it is likely `getComputedStyle` OP asks for...which I just now added to the dupe link(s)

Comment: @LGSon well my comment was for the comment added by tyr :) ... he got upvoted but it's wrong as we need computed style to get the style defined by CSS ...and that dup was already suggested  and when I saw it i found it was good for his needs

Comment: @TemaniAfif Ok...next time, add username in the comment, so it is clear to whom you address a comment :)

Answer (score 5):

Use `offsetWidth` and `offsetHeight`

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");
test.addEventListener("click", select);


function select(e) {
  var elementID = e.target.id;
  var element = document.getElementById(elementID);
  var offsetWidth = element.offsetWidth;

  var positionInfo = element.getBoundingClientRect();
  var height = positionInfo.height;
  var width = positionInfo.width;

  console.log('element', element);
  console.log('offsetWidth', offsetWidth);
  console.log('width', width);
  console.log('height', height);
}
```

```css
div#test {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="test"></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is `offsetWidth` the same as `width` in CSS. I mean not only in my case but in general

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133146/difference-between-style-width-and-offsetwidth-in-html @BlackBeard

Comment: As I expected it is not 100% the same. I need just simple `width`. Are there any possibilities to get it through JS?

Comment: I change the code, Check it @BlackBeard

Answer (score 0):

I think you need [`clientWidth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) and `clientHeight`.