# Obtaining real p width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am obtaining `<p>`'s width. The `<p>` is placed inside a `<div>` container with an `<input>` next to it. The `<div>` and all its contents were dynamically added to the DOM just before obtaining the width.

```
<div id="text-0">
<p>name</p>
<input>
</div>
```

`<p>`'s width if I look at the `$(p)` object properties in console is 35 (`offsetWidth`, `clientWidth`), but `$(p).width()` in the code returns 162, which is the width of the input element next to it. Same values are returned by all the methods `$(p).innerWidth()`, `$(p).outerWidth()`, `p.offsetWidth`, `p.clientWidth`, `p.getBoundingClientRect()`

Comment: Please provide a runnable [mcve] that reproduces the problem

Comment: Check [Difference between style.width and offsetwidth in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133146/difference-between-style-width-and-offsetwidth-in-html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what it was - my mistake it wasn't javascript/css problem as I thought. It had to do with using AngularJs `$compile` on the `div` which I didn't mention as I thought it wasn't related to the problem. The solution is to wait for $compile and then obtain the measurements.